# When storing scrapy results to database, how to avoid storing duplicates

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am just starting with scrapy and trying to develop a project where I scrape 'news links' from websites. For example, there is a website iltalehti.fi and I would like to scrape their news, let's say in every 5 minutes. Since each crawl will return duplicates, how do I avoid those duplicates from being stored in my database? So the end result would be a database containing only different entries but not the same news link twice (or 200 times in scenario if I run the crawler in every 5mins).

Any help is more than welcome and please note I know very little from python!

Comment: Welcome Hessu! Could you please give more details about your code? How is the data returned?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am afraid my code at this point is not relevant as I am just getting started. I managed to get what I need returned and even stored in SQlite. However, everytime I ran the crawl I got duplicates. So my database ended up having mostly the same articles stored (as the website does not update that often). Could you point me towards a solution, e.g. where could I start searching for solution!

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy uses pipelines to to do the extra processing(validating and filtering) with the data which is scraped from the websites.

You can write a pipleline which will be used to check the unique items and drop items which are duplicates.

Here is an example from the python docs:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

More info on pipelines [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Sayd Asim Hashmi. I am wondering how do I make the pipeline to check whether 'duplicate' already exist in the database?

Comment: You may make a database call inside of your init method to select all the items stored in the database and store their unique attribute (like slug) in the `ids_seen`, then you can check the each item scraped against these already store slugs to check if it is already stored in the database or not.

Comment: Thank you again Syed Asim Hasmi! Could you point me to an example or tutorial where I can learn more about this? My python skills are really low unfortunately. My DB Table will have 1) a title, 2) a link and 3) and a source website. How do I call e.g. all the titles and then check whether the newly scraped items contains the same?

Comment: You can google the libararies for database connectivity in python. There are tons of guides online.

Comment: You can google the libararies for database connectivity in python. There are tons of guides online.

Comment: Hi Syed Asim Hashmi, I've been looking into several guidelines but I don't quite get how to combine everything together. In the scrapy pipeline, should I fetch all items from the DB and then somehow compare whether the newly scraped items contain duplicates and if yes, then drop them? If so, could you help me a bit further how to do it in practice?